# How does the Java cast operator work?

Tags: java, casting, jvm

I am trying to debug an issue involving a ClassCastException in Java. In the interest of solving the issue I need to know what is going on when I cast from Object to a specific type. **Can anyone explain to me how the Java cast operator works at the Java level and the JVM level?**

Comment: Could you give an example of an instance where this occurs. For example, what class is the specific type and what class is the object?

Comment: Adam, I am probably going to ask a follow up question. Essentially I am creating a bean from Spring of type "com.generic.MyType" and it fails the cast to (MyType). I think this is probably a Spring issue over a Java one, but I am trying to be thorough.

Comment: @nemo: I know it's obvious, but in the source code, have you imported MyType as com.generic.MyType at the top? Or have you imported multiple packages (import org.generic.*; import org.other.*;) that may contain multiple classes named MyType and the compiler might be choosing the wrong one?

Comment: @Adam, actually I don't have imports for the cast type, and if I import it Netbeans says it is unused. However the error specifically can't cast to com.generic.MyType. I'll probably post the question with some real details later today if I can't make any progress, I'll give you a link here.

Comment: @nemo: Please do; we could probably help you much more that way.

Comment: Yeah I think this maybe an example of me trying to make a question too generic for my own good.

Comment: Follow up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841231/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.5) good enough?

> Casting conversion is applied to the operand of a cast operator (§15.16): the type of the operand expression must be converted to the type explicitly named by the cast operator. Casting contexts allow the use of:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.3)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5) optionally followed by an unchecked conversion (§5.1.9)
> - a narrowing reference conversion (§5.1.6) optionally followed by an unchecked conversion
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7)
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

Actually, maybe [this part](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#192526) is more relevant:

> The detailed rules for compile-time legality of a casting conversion of a value of compile-time reference type *S* to a compile-time reference type *T* are as follows:
>
> - If
>     *S* is a class type:
>
>   - If *T* is
>       a class type, then either |*S*|
>       <: |*T*|, or |*T*| <:
>       |*S*|; otherwise a compile-time
>       error occurs. Furthermore, if there
>       exists a supertype *X* of
>       *T*, and a supertype *Y* of
>       *S*, such that both *X* and
>       *Y* are provably distinct
>       parameterized types (§4.5),
>       and that the erasures of *X* and
>       *Y* are the same, a compile-time
>       error occurs.
>
>     If *T* is an interface type:
>
> - If
>     *S* is not a `final`
>     class (§8.1.1),
>     then, if there exists a supertype
>     *X* of *T*, and a supertype
>     *Y* of *S*, such that both
>     *X* and *Y* are provably
>     distinct parameterized types, and that
>     the erasures of *X* and *Y*
>     are the same, a compile-time error
>     occurs. Otherwise, the cast is always
>     legal at compile time (because even if
>     *S* does not implement *T*,
>     a subclass of *S* might).
>
>   If *S* is a
>     `final` class (§8.1.1),
>     then *S* must implement *T*,
>     or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> If *T*
>   is a type variable, then this
>   algorithm is applied recursively,
>   using the upper bound of *T* in
>   place of *T*.
>
> If *T* is
>   an array type, then *S* must be
>   the class `Object`, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> If *S* is
>   an interface type:
>
> - If *T* is
>     an array type, then *T* must
>     implement *S*, or a compile-time
>     error occurs.
>
>   If *T* is a  type that is not
>     `final` (§8.1.1),
>     then if there exists a supertype
>     *X* of *T*, and a supertype
>     *Y* of *S*, such that both
>     *X* and *Y* are provably
>     distinct parameterized types, and that
>     the erasures of *X* and *Y*
>     are the same, a compile-time error
>     occurs. Otherwise, the cast is always
>     legal at compile time (because even if
>     *T* does not implement *S*,
>     a subclass of *T* might).
>
>   If *T* is
>     a  type that is `final`,
>     then:
>
>   - If *S* is not a parameterized
>       type or a raw type, then *T* must
>       implement *S*, and the cast is
>       statically known to be correct, or a
>       compile-time error occurs.
>
>     Otherwise,
>       *S* is either a parameterized
>       type that is an invocation of some
>       generic type declaration *G*, or
>       a raw type corresponding to a generic
>       type declaration *G*. Then there
>       must exist a supertype *X* of
>       *T*, such that *X* is an
>       invocation of *G*, or a
>       compile-time error occurs.
>       Furthermore, if *S* and *X*
>       are provably distinct parameterized
>       types then a compile-time error
>       occurs.
>
> If *S* is
>   a type variable, then this algorithm
>   is applied recursively, using the
>   upper bound of *S* in place of
>   *S*.
>
> If
>   *S* is an array type *SC*[],
>   that is, an array of components of
>   type *SC*:
>
> - If *T* is a
>     class type, then if *T* is not
>     `Object`, then a
>     compile-time error occurs (because
>     `Object` is the only class
>     type to which arrays can be assigned).
>
>   If *T*
>     is an interface type, then a
>     compile-time error occurs unless
>     *T* is the type
>     `java.io.Serializable` or
>     the type `Cloneable`, the
>     only interfaces implemented by arrays.
>
>   If *T*
>     is a type variable, then:
>
>   - If the upper
>       bound of *T* is
>       `Object` or the type
>       `java.io.Serializable` or
>       the type `Cloneable`, or a
>       type variable that *S* could
>       legally be cast to by recursively
>       applying these rules, then the cast is
>       legal (though unchecked).
>
>     If the upper
>       bound of *T* is an array type
>       *TC[]*, then a compile-time error
>       occurs unless the type *SC[]* can
>       be cast to *TC[]* by a recursive
>       application of these compile-time
>       rules for casting.
>
>     Otherwise, a
>       compile-time error occurs.
>
>   If *T* is
>     an array type *TC*[], that is, an
>     array of components of type *TC*,
>     then a compile-time error occurs
>     unless one of the following is true:
>
> *TC* and *SC* are the
>   same primitive type.
>
> *TC* and
>   *SC* are reference types and type
>   *SC* can be cast to *TC* by
>   a recursive application of these
>   compile-time rules for casting.

Perfectly clear now, isn't it? :D

In other words, this is the best I can do without knowing more details about your problem.

Comment: Hmm... I went and stripped out all links from the second part, but I don't know what's wrong with the first part.

Comment: If anybody knows why the link is acting weird, please go ahead and fix it!

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like anchor tags?

Comment: But there aren't any anchor tags; I stripped them all out already.

Answer (score 6):

A likely cause of class cast mystifcation is that not only do the types have to match but also they must be loaded by the same classloader.

You should be able to dump not only the type hierarchy but also the identity of the classloader for each class.

These kind of problems are not uncommon in appserver-style environments where application code and infratructure code are deliberately isolated - for example if system classes are accidentally included in applciation JARs you can have two copies of the "same" class inthe JVM and life gets confusing

Comment: "You should be able to dump not only the type hierarchy but also the identity of the classloader for each class." How do you implement this?

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however after running .getClassLoader() on them both classes appear to be loaded by the same class loader.

Comment: Just for other folks who may be troubleshooting, there is more about the class loader issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class.

Answer (score 3):

Other useful and authoritative references are found in the Java Virtual Machine Specification, specifically [§2.6.5, "Narrowing Reference Conversions",](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html#32879) and especially the definition of the [`checkcast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Instructions2.doc2.html#checkcast) instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Casting asserts that the runtime type of an object is compatible with the given static type, and thus allows you to call methods of that type on the object.

Here obj is a Integer object, but only accessible though an Object reference:

```
Object obj = new Integer(1);
```

Casting lets you treat it as an Integer (or some superclass of Integer) again:

```
System.out.println(((Integer) obj).intValue());
```

ClassCastException occours when the static type given does not match the runtime type of the object:

```
System.out.println(((Float) obj).intValue()); // runtime error
```

You can find the runtime type of any object by using getClass() and the various Class methods:

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass()); // prints "class java.lang.Integer"
```