# Converting object received from Redis fails using class.cast and works using ObjectMapper.convertValue

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Whats the difference between using `Class.cast` to convert an object to a certain type v/s doing the same using `ObjectMapper.convertValue`.
I am assuming cast also internally uses `jackson` but I think that's not the case here.

**My RedisTemplateConfig:**

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Object> reactiveRedisTemplate(
    ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    StringRedisSerializer keySerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> valueSerializer =
        new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);
    RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Object> builder =
        RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext(keySerializer);
    RedisSerializationContext<String, Object> context =
        builder.value(valueSerializer).build();

    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(factory, context);
}
```

**SetValueInRedis:**

```
@Override
public <T> Mono<T> setValue(String key, Object value, Class<T> clazz) {
    return reactiveValueOps.set(key, value,
            Duration.ofDays(SESSION_PERSISTENCE_DURATION))
            .map(o -> clazz.cast(value));
}
```

**Working GetValueInRedis:**

```
@Override
public <T> Mono<T> getValue(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
        return reactiveValueOps.get(key)
            .flatMap(val -> Mono.justOrEmpty(objectMapper.convertValue(val, clazz)));
}
```

**Error version of Get Value:**

```
@Override
public <T> Mono<T> getValue(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    return reactiveValueOps.get(key)
        .flatMap(o -> Mono.justOrEmpty(clazz.cast(o)));
    }
```

**----EDIT----**

If we notice the serializer used for Redis(`Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer`): while saving the object to redis it works fine. But while reading(get) `cast` fails and `objectMappper` works. When I am using `Jackson2JsonRedis` serializer, shouldn't `get` command return an object which should be castable using Class.cast command itself?

Answer (score 1):

`Class.cast` and `ObjectMapper.convertValue` are two totally different mechanisms. `Class.cast` does not create new object, only returns old reference with new type. Below you can see how `Class.cast` is implemented:

```
public T cast(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))
        throw new ClassCastException(cannotCastMsg(obj));
    return (T) obj;
}
```

`Jackson` from other side creates new object from different hierarchy and copy internal structure. For example, can convert `Map` to `POJO` and `POJO` to `Map` using reflection. But you can not cast reference to `Map` on reference to `POJO`.

Summary: only `convertValue` method from these two really does conversion from one instance to new one and from one type to new one. `cast` only tries to change reference type to the same object.

See also:

- [Java Class.cast() vs. cast operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555326/java-class-cast-vs-cast-operator)
- [Convert a Map to a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428817/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-a-pojo)
- [How does Java Object casting work behind the scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405377/how-does-java-object-casting-work-behind-the-scene)
- [Java casting implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886613/java-casting-implementation?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How does the Java cast operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840322/how-does-the-java-cast-operator-work?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If you notice the serializer used for Redis, while saving the object to redis it works fine. But while reading cast fails and object Mappper works. When I am using Jackson2JsonRedis serializer, shouldn't `get` command return an object which should be castable using Class.cast command?

Comment: Thanks. I understand why ObjectMapper convertValue works because it tries to create a new object from the passed one. But should by Redis Serializer would have done that thereby making my object castable? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Karshit, what `reactiveValueOps.get(key)` method returns? Why do we need `flatMap`. I have never used `Redis`, just wanted to explain what is the difference between `Class.cast` and `ObjectMapper.convertValue`. If  you think you should not convert anything create new question with `redis` tag and ask why do you need to do this. Right now I do not have to much information about your project and knowledge about `Redis` to give you good answer.