# Set one of the attribute become an URL (hyperlink)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

Am I able to change one the attribute become an URL(hyperlink) so user will be able to click on it and redirect to another page.

Any expert out there able to help me? Thank you so much and have a nice day!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2nd.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>THE SUPER SEARCH</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Here's the following results</h4>

<%
String testresults=(String)request.getAttribute("testresults");
out.print("" + testresults);
%>
<br>
<% 
String testcontent=(String)request.getAttribute("testcontent");
out.print("" + testcontent);
%>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which line is `Hello.supersearchServlet.doGet(supersearchServlet.java:66)` ... could you comment that line in your post..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Java cast operator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840322/how-does-the-java-cast-operator-work)

Comment: Is this line. String content = (String) d.get("content"); below the for thank you so much! @Noushad

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error in this line:

```
 String content = (String) d.get("content");
```

d.get("content") is an ArrayList, not a String.

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
<a href="<%=testresults%>"><%=testresults%></a>
```