# Java casting / classloader issues

Tags: java, casting, java-native-interface, classloader, javax.imageio

Here is the simplified version of the problem:

```
 SomeClass c = (SomeClass) obj.getSomeClassParent()
```

not always but it happens sometimes to trigger exception

```
 org.somepackage.SomeClass can't be cast to org.somepackage.SomeClass
```

How  is this possible ?  I suppose it has something to do with the fact that JAI imageio is   native lib, but relay how can this happen ? I'm probably missing something but what ?

```
I'm using JAI imageio version 1.1 
dcm4che 2.0.21  DICOM lib
```

Here is the original code

```
  ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(src);
  Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
  ImageReader reader = iter.next();
  DicomImageReadParam param = (DicomImageReadParam) reader.getDefaultReadParam();
```

And the original exception

```
org.dcm4che2.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReadParam can't be cast to    
org.dcm4che2.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReadParam
```

[Exception Image http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/3894/exception.jpg](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/3894/exception.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it can happen if

1. a `SomeClass` instance was loaded from ClassLoader X (so its class is `SomeClass` of CL X or let's call it: `CL(X).SomeClass`)
2. but it is being cast in a different class loader. E.g. the current Threads class loader is Y so `SomeClass` is actually `CL(Y).SomeClass`

So you have:

- instance class = `CL(X).SomeClass`
- class cast target = `CL(Y).SomeClass`

Or in other words - not the same class - thus the class cast exception.

---

Possible duplicate of: [ClassCastException when casting to the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class) - it has some good suggestions as well.

Comment: You basically have it here.  The problem is that each instance is loaded by a different classloader, thus getClass() on each of these instances will return a different instance of the same class.  You should edit this somewhat since a Class is loaded in both classloaders, not an instance in one and a Class in another, that isn't actually possible.

Comment: True that `SomeClass` is loaded in both classloaders, but I ment that the casting is from an instance of a class loaded in CL X, to a class loaded to CL Y. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Ehrann Mehdan - much more clear, but you should remove the bit about serialization, that isn't applicable in this case.

Comment: @Robin @ Ehrann the problem is  in the class-loader for sure. But why i have different class loaders in one app it is still mistery. I'm tying to find nice solution.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but worth a look: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24566

Answer (score 2):

i would guess that you have a problem due to the mismatch between classloaders and native libraries.  native libraries are loaded and associated with a classloader, however, the programs can only *really* load one instance of a native library.  so, if you load the native lib in classloader A, and classes which it outputs will be associated with classloader A.  if you later load the same native library in classloader B, you aren't really loading it again, and it will still be passing out classes for classloader A.  so, either you redeployed your webapp, or you have 2 webapps in the same webserver which use the same native library.

if possible, you should try to put the native library in the base classpath of the webserver, so that it will be loaded by the base classloader, and thus be usable by any webapp.  if you can't do this, and the problem is only a redeployment issue, then you might want to undeploy and wait a bit before redeploying (in theory, the native lib will be unloaded when the classloader with which it is associated is GCed, but of course, this can take an unknown amount of time).

Answer (score 1):

Strange have you tried casting it to a Object it extends, not sure if it has the functionality you require but might be worth trying to see if it still throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

From the image I see that it looks like a web application. I read 'catalina'. So there is a big chance, that it is a pure classloading problem.

It could happen, for example, if the ImageReader you get from the ImageIO class was loaded by a different classloader (maybe because it's deployed in a different webapp), so the DicomImageReadParam object returned by the getDefaultReadParam() method is an instance of a - technically spoken - different class.