# ClassCastException: JPA -> Bean value (different ClassLoaders)

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, classcastexception

I get a ClassCastException when assigning an object from JPA to an attribute of a ManagedBean:

```
Object r = query.getSingleResult(); // javax.persistence.Query
ClassLoader c1 = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
ClassLoader c2 = r.getClass().getClassLoader();
user = (User) r; // blubb.model.User
```

The problem is that c1 (ManagedBean) and c2 (EclipseLink) are different ClassLoaders:

c1: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
c2: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are the classes loaded with two different class loaders?

Comment: That's what I ask myself too. I don't specify anything about ClassLoaders.

Comment: Nonetheless, you are are sure the Object r is of type User, right? I mean, if you println r.getClass(), it is a User, correct?

Comment: Yes, same Class, different ClassLoader - that's why the cast fails.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `query.getSingleResult()` into a method that uses generics and assign directly? Well... probably you will get the same runtime exception. But it's good for abstraction and less coupling.

Comment: Yes, tried it. Also tried createQuery(String, Class<T>). Same problem.

Comment: Well, a good start is find out why you have two different class loaders with different versions of the class User. Another thing we need to know is if the two class loaders are related. You can print the hierarchy of class loaders in a loop using ClassLoader.getParent() until you reach the bootstrap class loader(i.e. parent == null). If you do the same with both class loaders we can determine in which point they are related.

Comment: Maybe [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your environment?  Are you using Java EE, Spring, OSGi?  Which server, WLS, WAS, GF?

Did you redeploy your application?  Is the persistence unit managed or non-managed?

It could be that you redeployed your application, but never closed the EntityManagerFactory, so it is still deployed with the old classes.

Comment: JSF with EclipseLink and PrimeFaces on GlassFish. You're right, I only get the error sometimes after redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem. Simple JSF project with EclipseLink 2.5.2 JPA  inside of Glassfish 4.1.1.

Solved by correctly closing the `EntityManagerFactory`. I reccomend to use `ServletContextListener` (`@WebListener`)  (take look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862798/3797793) or [here](http://www.hhutzler.de/blog/jpa-best-practice-to-get-and-close-entitymanagerfactory-to-avoid-unknown-entity-bean-class-error/)).