# JPA, nothing is added to Database when commit

Tags: jpa, dao

I have two tables (command and commandLine), i want to write in both when i insert a new command
Here is my Command Object, I use a OneToMany to map with the object CommandLine

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_commands")
public class Command {

    @Id @Getter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCommand;

    @Getter @Setter
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "commandDate")
    private String date;

    @Getter @Setter
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CommandLine.class, mappedBy = "idCommand")
    private List<CommandLine> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public Command(User user, String date) {
        this.user = user;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Command() {
    }
```

and my CommandLine object, I use ManyToOne to map with the object Command

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_commandlines")
public class CommandLine {

    @Id @Getter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCommandLine;

    @Getter
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Command.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCommand", nullable = false)
    private Command idCommand;

    @Getter @Setter
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Article.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idArticle", nullable = false)
    private Article article;

    @Getter @Setter
    private int quantity;


    public CommandLine(Article article, int quantity) {
        this.article = article;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
```

and my CommandDAO

```
public class CommandDAO implements IDao<Command> {

    @Override
    public boolean create(Command object) {
        connect().persist(object);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I use interface

```
public interface IDao<T> {

    default EntityManager connect() {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
        EntityManager entityManager;

        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("webstore");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        return entityManager;
    }

    default T read(Long id){return null;}
    default List<T> getAll() {return null;}
    default boolean create(T object) {return false;}
    default boolean update(T object) {return false;}
    default boolean delete(T object) {return false;}
    default Long getCount() {return 1L;}
}
```

I have no error, but nothing is writing in my db, I have no problem to retrieve data from the db with this structure, but impossible to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not applying the changes because there is no transaction and so the persist operation is not flushed to the database.

Here a simplified example of what the code should look like:

```
public class CommandDAO implements IDao<Command> {

    @Override
    public boolean create(Command object) {
        EntityManager em = connect();
        try {
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          em.persist(object);
          em.getTransaction().commit();
          return true;
        }
        finally {
          em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, there is no reason to create the `EntityManagerFactory` every time `connect()` is called. The creation of the factory is quite heavy but the factory is thread safe, you can reuse it when you need it.
It makes sense to create an `EntityManager` every time you need it, but you have to close it when you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you also for your advise, where is the good place to create EntityManagerFactory ?

Comment: It depends, but usually the factory is created by a different object when the application starts and then, when you need it, you can get an already created factory from there without having to call `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` every time.

Comment: If you are deploying your application on a application server, it usually creates the factory at start up

Comment: in my case, I use a simple example of servlets, JSP and JPA, I enter to my application within ServletLogin.java, should I put the factory in this servlet? thank for your time

Comment: it's okay, i find this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862700/best-practice-to-get-entitymanagerfactory very good practice