# Inheritance in java, casting subclass to superclass

Tags: eclipse, inheritance, classcastexception

I am writing a software in java and this inheritance problem always crops up. Funny enough, I don't get problems when i run the program in my `IDE` (Eclipse Kepler) but once i export it to an executable jar, problem starts. I think I am the only one experiencing this problem because all searches on google show  the direct opposite.

My problem is I have an interface named `VoteType`. This interface is implemented by several concrete classes. I save the concrete implementation to a file using `XMLEncoder` and retrieve it using `XMLDecoder`.

But when i try to cast it to the interface it implements `VoteType`, I get a `ClassCastException`. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: please add code snippets

Answer (score 0):

You are not precise enough to track this down, but I assume that the interface and the object implementing the interface and which is created via XMLDecoder are created by different class loaders. Could that be the reason?

See also this problem: [Solution for the ClassCastException due to ClassLoader issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074532/solution-for-the-classcastexception-due-to-classloader-issue)

Comment: Well, i have another class loader which loads plugins but this class loader for the thread causing the problem is the system class loader

Comment: Either they need to be loaded from the same classloader, or the base type has to be loaded from a parent classloader of the one that loaded the subtype. How are the classloaders loading XMLEncoder and VoteType related?

Comment: The system class loader loads both classes. My problem is why it would work fine in eclipse but start misbehaving once it is exported to an executable  jar. Even the instanceof operator returns false when i check if(serializedVote instanceof VoteType)

Comment: Eclipse might run under a different JVM and/or load a different implementation of XMLDecoder compared to running the executable-jar. Can you please add a System.out.print of the seralizedVote.class and VoteType.class with details about the class loader, etc.