# java.lang.ClassCastException with the same class object

Tags: ejb-3.0, jpql, classcastexception, stateless-session-bean

This piece of code irritates me, 
sometimes it working and some other times it doesn't !

> The NamedQuery : (name = "User.findByLogin", query = "SELECT u
>   FROM User u WHERE u.login = :login")

```
public User findByLogin(String login) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByLogin");
        query.setParameter("login", login);
        try {
            return (User) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The error make me crazy !

Avertissement: EJB5184:**A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB UserFacade**, method: public dz.admin.entity.User dz.admin.service.UserFacade.findByLogin(java.lang.String)
Avertissement: javax.ejb.EJBException
.... **Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: dz.elit.admin.entity.User cannot be cast to dz.elit.admin.entity.User** at dz.elit.admin.service.UserFacade.findByLogin(UserFacade.java:45)

Answer (score 19):

I face same issue in my **spring-boot** application and waste my so much time to solve it.

Issue is generate because of classloaders.

Classloaders of Model class and Session class both are different.

```
System.out.println("ClassLoader : " + Employee.class.getClassLoader());
System.out.println(session.getClass().getClassLoader()); //Hibernate Session object

ClassLoader : org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@a3af3c
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93
```

I face this issue because of this dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

When i comment this then my code working fine, so i suggest you to please check your jars.

```
System.out.println("ClassLoader : " + Employee.class.getClassLoader());
System.out.println(session.getClass().getClassLoader()); //Hibernate Session object

ClassLoader : sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93
```

Hope this answer help you.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my evening. I've spent around 3 hours debugging this issue in spring boot with devtools.

Comment: My evening too :-). Incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be that you have different classloaders. The same class loaded in a different classloader is still considered different by the JVM.

To verify this, you could try to catch the exception and print/log the classloaders.

```
public User findByLogin(String login) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByLogin");
    query.setParameter("login", login);
    Object result = null;
    try {
        result = query.getSingleResult();
        return (User) result ;
    } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException ex) {
        return null;
    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
        logger.info("Object classloader: " + result.getClass().getClassLoader());
        logger.info("Target class classloader: " + User.class.getClassLoader());
        if(result.getClass().getClassLoader() != User.class.getClassLoader()) {
            logger.warn("Different classloaders detected!");
        }
    }
}
```

As for the solution, that of course depends on the rest of your setup... To get you started, I can give you some pointers to related questions asked before. Maybe some of the answers there can be helpful to you:

- [Solution for the ClassCastException due to ClassLoader issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074532/solution-for-the-classcastexception-due-to-classloader-issue)
- [ClassCastException because of classloaders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865917/classcastexception-because-of-classloaders)
- [cast across classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591779/cast-across-classloader)
- [ClassCastException when casting to the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class)

Some of the suggested solutions include changing your classloader setup, using a common interface, or serializing/deserializing your object.

Answer (score -1):

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByLogin");
...
return (User) query.getSingleResult();
```

Probably you will need to check whether User really exist (not null).
sometime it will be null and you will need to re-refer it

> sometimes it working and some other times it doesn't !