# ClassCastException to the same class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to integrate Spring Boot and Hibernate and I want to access database without using repositories (I succeed to make all the CRUD operation using database configuration inside *application.properties* and getting all I need by repositories).
Basically I have a *ClassCastException* in the following code:

```
 Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<User> appUsers =null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("FROM User WHERE id = :id");   
            query.setParameter("id", id);  //the id is given by parameter
            appUsers = query.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            session.close();
        } 
        User user = appUsers.get(0);
```

At the final line I'm getting this exception telling me it can't cast from User to User (*same class*). I know Query is deprecated an I have tried alternative but I'm still getting the same result. Even *dto (data transfer object)* haven't helped me out.
Also I have run in debugger and I'm getting the correct result from database (*MySql*) but when I try to get the first object (User) which exist throws me this exception. When I verify `User.class.isInstance(appUsers.get(0))` the result is false. I know the User class is correctly written according to the hibernate mapping practice.

What have I done wrong?

I have searched online for other "solutions"  to solve this issue, but none worked for me or relates with this exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your import for the `User` class in your class. is it the same as the one expected?

Comment: I think you should do en explicit cast :User user = (User) appUsers.get(0);

Comment: What's the exact message of the exception you're getting? Also, check your imports as @pleft suggested

Comment: I've tried explicit cast. The import is correct and in debugger attributes are correctly correlated.

Comment: _classCastException_ <package>.User cannot be cast to <package>.User . The package is the same.

Comment: did you tried this: User user = (User)query.uniqueResult();

Comment: Not working. In the result list (after database query) i have an object that have same structure as class User (_hibernate entity class_) but somehow it is not the same instance.

Comment: I mean instead of  `appUsers = query.list();` just use `User user = (User)query.uniqueResult();` because you are querying over id and it is unique

Comment: Share the stack trace.

Comment: Then delete `User user = appUsers.get(0);` and you will not get classCastException

Comment: I've tried `(User)query.uniqueResult();` and I have the same exception. When I try the same piece of code outside spring specific classes (_a separate main method_ that is not running with spring configuration) everything works fine and the cast is done without any problem.

Comment: did you tried to remove `tx = session.beginTransaction();` ? because it's not needed here

Comment: I've tried alternative that don't use Transaction at all. But thanks for observation.

Comment: I think that Spring influences to the class User. Different class-loaders, proxy or something else. Thats why all works fine outside spring. Maybe [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865259/java-lang-classcastexception-with-the-same-class-object).

Comment: I know that Spring influence somehow my class. When I've tried with dto i separate the entities so one class for API and JPA repository and one for hibernate. Same cast exception for the hibernate entity class. As your suggestion, I also tried to serialize the object and to create a _hash_ method inside User class.