# Keycloak with Tomcat: org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal cannot be cast to org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal

Tags: java, tomcat, keycloak

I am running Keycloak with the Tomcat adapter.  But, when I try to get the KeycloakPrincipal, it errors out with this;

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal cannot be cast to org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal

My code is very simple and my environment is setup exactly like the KeyCloak docs say it should be.

```
{
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)getApp().getFromUserStorage(HttpServletRequest.class.getName());
    KeycloakPrincipal kcp = (KeycloakPrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();
}
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong here?   The only solutions I've found by googling have to do with Maven configuration, but Maven isn't being used here.

Comment: Check if you have duplicate keycloak libraries in the classpath at runtime .

Comment: I thought about that too.  The only reference to the Keycloak objects is through a reference to the Tomcat library.

Comment: [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865259/java-lang-classcastexception-with-the-same-class-object) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  One of my libraries was causing a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Remoing the keycloak adapters fromWEB-INF directory solves this issue.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Text only answers are usually not very useful unless they explain what they do. Please consider adding an explanation of what you changed or wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue.

solution :

a) Project/maven keycloak jar and tomcat/lib keycloak jars should have same version

b) Add scope as provided in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
        <version>17.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```