# classcast exception from a extension class loaded class

Tags: java, classloader, classcastexception

Ran into a issue today.

```
abc.ClassA a = (abc.ClassA) request.getsession().getAttribute();
```

and i  get classcast exception here.

`abc.ClassA` is referenced from a jar file in the project build path.

I also read about the class being loaded with different class loaders and the issue could be becoz of that.

Comment: Show us the full stack trace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: vss.YearMakeModel cannot be cast to vss.YearMakeModel
 at com.gm.nvls.controller.WidgetController.getMake(WidgetController.java:271)
 at com.gm.nvls.controller.WidgetController.doPost(WidgetController.java:83)
 at com.gm.nvls.controller.WidgetController.doGet(WidgetController.java:423)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class was loaded by two different classloaders.
I guess your jar is located twice in the classloaders hierarchy: once somewhere in the parent path (lib of weblogic?) and once at a child (war?)

The best solution is putting a jar only once at classpath.

If this is impossible, you can try to change client-first/client-last behavior of classloaders.

Tip: you can debug it and get the problematic classloaders quite easily. Stop in debugger in the problematic line and then compare `request.getsession().getAttribute().getClass().getClassloader()` and `abc.ClassA.class.getClassloader()`