# Why would casting work locally but not on a server?

Tags: java, tomcat, imap, jakarta-mail

This is a bit of a specific problem, but I am using javamail to connect to an IMAP server to pull some messages, and when I run my program locally in the command line it runs just fine, but when it is uploaded to tomcat to run, I get this casting error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
```

the line of code is:

```
MimeMultipart mp;
mp = ((MimeMultipart)message.getContent());
```

message is defined as:

```
Message message = null;
message = folder.getMessageByUID(14299);
```

Im not sure why I can cast it when it is run locally, but it crashes on the server. I am using the same message both times, it is hard coded, so there is no chance I will be pulling a message that is not a MimeMultipart. Any ideas? If you need me to post anything else, I will, just ask. Thanks!

Comment: Are the client and server using different JVMs?

Comment: Yes, the client and server are using different JVMs.

Comment: Appears to be a ClassLoader issue.

Comment: This is all Im getting when it crashes... 

java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
 at com.wingdom.connect.IMAP_Connect.map(IMAP_Connect.java:72)
 ... 24 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error message of the type :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: CLASS cannot be cast to CLASS
```

often indicates a classloader issue. You are trying from one ClassLoader to cast to an instance which resides in another ClassLoader.

I am guessing that the javamail jar are in the /WEB-INF/lib folder of your webapp. In that case, if they are also in the lib folder of tomcat, you will have that exact message.

[See this link for more information on tomcat ClassLoading.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

One way to fix this is to delete the javamail libs from your tomcat installation and leave them in the webapp, or, to not includes them in the war.

Comment: This sounds like what is happening, let me play with it and see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a Classloader issue, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class) for several possible solutions:

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information available to us in the current state of the question, the best way to arrive at your solution is to verify the ClassLoader that loaded MimeMultipart:

```
ClassLoader myClassLoader = new MyClass().getClass().getClassLoader();
```

However, going down that path could take you longer than expected.

There's a good chance that this is a localized error on your Tomcat installation. If you're able to try it on a different server like **GlassFish**, or perhaps a **fresh install of Tomcat**, you may find the problem resolved. You've already confirmed that your program is fine via command line.