# Java EE can't cast class from database to same runtime class

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, classcastexception

I'm trying to retrieve a class persisted in a MySQL database, but Java EE throws the appended exceptions. The affected method retrieves an object from the database (using Eclipselink and JPA) by its primary key and tries to store it in a parameterized list, here `List<Landlord>` for testing purposes, but usually `List<Account>`, whereas account is the superclass of landlord and multiple other classes. The method works in JUnit and JSF2.1 but not as part of a Webservice (jax-ws, Glassfish).

---

The following line from the exceptions is especially interesting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: model.Landlord cannot be cast to model.Landlord
```

---

The method:

```
public Account getAccount(String email) {
    Account acc = null;

    String[][] params = { { "email", email } };
    List<Landlord> query = db.namedQuery("Account.find", params);

    if (query.size() == 1) {
        acc = query.get(0);
    }

    return acc;

}
```

The exceptions:

```
[2013-09-16T14:27:12.166+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1379334432166] [levelValue: 1000] [[

javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy409.getAccountByEmail(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:193)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: model.Landlord cannot be cast to model.Landlord
    at bean.AccountBean.getAccount(AccountBean.java:54)
    at service.FeWoServiceBean.getAccountByEmail(FeWoServiceBean.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:193)
    ... 57 more
]]

[2013-09-16T14:27:12.171+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [ejb.system_exception] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1379334432171] [levelValue: 900] [[
  EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB FeWoServiceBean, method: public model.Account service.FeWoServiceBean.getAccountByEmail(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]]

[2013-09-16T14:27:12.171+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1379334432171] [levelValue: 900] [[

javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy409.getAccountByEmail(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:193)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: model.Landlord cannot be cast to model.Landlord
    at bean.AccountBean.getAccount(AccountBean.java:54)
    at service.FeWoServiceBean.getAccountByEmail(FeWoServiceBean.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:193)
    ... 57 more
]]
```

Comment: class objects were loaded with different classloaders it seems. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class) helps.

Comment: Can you post the filesystem layout of your application? And the places where `model.Landlord.class` is located?

Comment: model
--Account
--Landlord
--Tenant
--Admin
--Reseller
--Reservation
--etc
service
--EntityManagerBean
--FeWoServiceBean