# ClassCastException with same type and caching in ibm integration bus

Tags: java, serialization, esb, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

i am implementing caching solution in `ibm integration bus` using `java` inside the message flows and the logic is implemented like the following :

1. I built the base `class` : `Deparment` :

   public class Department implements Serializable { // the members with setters and getters }
2. I built a `Wrapper class` that defines an `ArrayList<Department>`

   public class CachedDepartment implements Serializable {
           private ArrayList departments;
           // with setters and getters ....
       }
3. I created class that implements the `cache` solution to `set` new `value`
   and to `get` the `value`

to `set`:

```
MbGlobalMap globalMap = MbGlobalMap.getGlobalMap(globalMapName);
    globalMap.put(key, value);
```

to `get`:

```
CachedDepartment cacheddept = null;
        MbGlobalMap globalMap = MbGlobalMap.getGlobalMap(globalMapName);
        cacheddept = (CachedDepartment)  globalMap.get(key);
```

4. i created `jar` file and put it on `classLoader` directory and its run when setting `cache`, the problem is when running the get functionality.

   java.lang.ClassCastException: cache.entities.CachedDepartment incompatible with cache.entities.CachedDepartment

I read this link [ClassCastException when casting to the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class) but still i don't know how to solve it in `IBM Integration bus` that run on `JDK 1.7` any ideas ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the project containing the CachedDepartment and Department classes is still in the Project References of your IIB Java project, what makes the Toolkit deploy that to the integration server, but that project should only be deployed to the shared-classes directory.

So remove the project containing the cached entities from the Project references and the Java Build Path of your IIB Java project, and add it as an external JAR to the Libraries under Java Build Path.

More details here:

https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2013/10/17/how-to-store-logical-message-tree-data-in-the-global-cache-using-jaxb-in-ibm-integration-bus-v9/

Comment: Thank you it works , i put the jar on `classes` folder of the server and i added the `jar` in the `buildpath` for `IIB` project.