# RecyclerView cannot be cast to RecyclerView on Xposed

Tags: casting, android-recyclerview, xposed

I started to develop an xposed module but now I get a strange error.
I used

```java
RecyclerView player_recycler_view=(RecyclerView)card_content.getChildAt(2)
```

to get the RecyclerView. `card_content` is the parent of the RecyclerView.

I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

It makes no sense! With the others child of `card_content` everything is working fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could be a classloader issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassCastException when casting to the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrew Sun should be correct, I have observed this pattern before for `android.support` classes.

Try to compare both classloaders:

```
if (RecyclerView.class.getClassLoader() == card_content.getChildAt(2).getClass().getClassLoader()) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Same classloader");
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "Another classloader");
}
```

If they are indeed from different class loaders, using `getClass` on the `card_content.getChildAt(2)` and reflection you should be able to invoke on its methods.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem! Thank you