# Deserialized after persistence in Database object can't be casted into source Class: ClassCastException: TestDomain cannot be cast to TestDomain

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

I faced with following problem in `spring-session`:

```
@RestController
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test() {
        Session session = sessionRepository.createSession();
        TestDomain testDomain = new TestDomain("a", 1);
        session.setAttribute(session.getId(), testDomain);
        sessionRepository.save(session);

        Session session1 = sessionRepository.getSession(session.getId());
        Object testDomainObj = session1.getAttribute(session1.getId());
        // I wonder why TestDomainObj is not an instance of TestDomain??
        System.out.println("Does testDomainObj from session represent the instance of TestDomain class: " + (testDomainObj instanceof TestDomain));

        // java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.demo.TestDomain cannot be cast to com.example.demo.TestDomain
        TestDomain testDomain1 = (TestDomain) testDomainObj;
        System.out.println(testDomain1);
    }
}
```

I tried to search and found that after getting `testDomainObj` it is the instance of Object class. So, it is clear that deserialized object loses its metainformation.

I configured `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    SessionRepository sessionFactoryBean(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JdbcOperationsSessionRepository(jdbcTemplate, transactionManager);
    }
}
```

And activated it in `application.properties`:

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initializer.enabled=true
```

Last thing `testDomain` object has been saved in Database after executing `sessionRepository.save(session);`

How to understand and cope with this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't `TestDomain testDomain1 = session1.getAttribute(session1.getId());` work?

Comment: Firstly I tried this but I got ClassCastException such as when I am casting `Object testDomain1` to `TestDomain` class above

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I answer on my question. In my case I should specify ClassLoader for the deserializer like this:

```
@Bean
SessionRepository sessionFactoryBean(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    JdbcOperationsSessionRepository sessionRepository = new JdbcOperationsSessionRepository(jdbcTemplate, transactionManager);
    GenericConversionService conversionService = new GenericConversionService();
    conversionService.addConverter(Object.class, byte[].class,
            new SerializingConverter());
    conversionService.addConverter(byte[].class, Object.class,
            new DeserializingConverter(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));
    sessionRepository.setConversionService(conversionService);
    return sessionRepository;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering this problem because you register `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` bean manually rather than reusing Spring Session JDBC configuration facilities, i.e. `@EnableJdbcHttpSession`. See [the relevant code in `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.3.x/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/config/annotation/web/http/JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L86-L111).

Spring Boot makes this even easier by providing auto-configuration support for Spring Session so you don't even need to use `@EnableJdbcHttpSession`. Simply adding `spring.session.store-type=jdbc` to configuration properties takes care of everything for you.