# PrimefacesExtensions Sheet component on cell edit throws method not found exception

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

When trying to edit the cell, method not found exception is thrown. I tried using an `ajaxBehaviourEvent`, but it is throwing `ClassCastException`: Sheet can not be cast to Sheet

```
//view     
<p:ajax  listener="#{dataListView.cellEditEvent}"  process=":form:sheet" update=":form:sheet" >
</p:ajax>

// method 
public void cellEditEvent(SheetEvent event) {

    org.primefaces.extensions.component.sheet.Sheet sheet =  event.getSheet();
    List<SheetUpdate> updates = sheet.getUpdates();
    HashSet<Sample> processed = new HashSet<Sample>();
    int rowUpdates = 0;
    for (SheetUpdate update : updates) {
        Sample asset = (Sample) update.getRowData();
        if (processed.contains(asset))
            continue;
        entityManager.merge(asset);
        System.out.println("Asset " + asset.getEmail() + " updated.");
        rowUpdates++;
        showSampleData();
    }
    sheet.commitUpdates();
}
```

Using PrimeFaces 6.2 and PrimeFacesExtension 6.2.3 and Seam 2.3

Comment: and if i use AjaxBehaviourEvent :Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.extensions.component.sheet.Sheet cannot be cast to org.primefaces.extensions.component.sheet.Sheet                                                   public void cellEditEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
  
  org.primefaces.extensions.component.sheet.Sheet sheet =  (Sheet) event.getComponent();
  List<SheetUpdate> updates = sheet.getUpdates();

Comment: Which event is the ajax listener listening to? Add `event="change"` to your `p:ajax`.

Comment: Added event="change" and changed cellEditEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) then error is >>>  org.primefaces.extensions.component.sheet.Sheet cannot be cast to org.primefaces.extensions.component.sheet.Sheet

Comment: That seems to be a classloader issue.

Comment: Any work around for this @AshishMathew , why means required jar files has been placed correctly and no dependency issue . iam using primefaces 6.2 and primefaces extension 6.2.3.jar

Comment: You can refer to this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class.

Comment: Rechecked the lib files , as per the primefaces documentation primefaces 6.2 has been added to make pm-extension 6.2.3 to work !! 
jars are updating in lib as well as war/lib too through build.xml
And for AjaxBehaviorEvent event is called correctly but the issue is with Sheet casting .

Comment: sorry for late reply . thanks @AshishMathew . there where two PF jars which were adding in to the project