# ClassCastException marshalling objects in threads created with ManagedExecutorService

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, jboss, classcastexception

I've ran into a problem using Spring's and ManagedExecutorService in Jboss. When marshalling objects in a runnable I get a ClassCastException saying class can't be cast to the same class, seems like the classloader sticks around when application is redeployed and new tasks are submitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassCastException when casting to the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly what is causing your error without seeing code and the full error.

However here is perhaps a relevant thread : [ClassCastException when casting to the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826319/classcastexception-when-casting-to-the-same-class)

As said in this thread, maybe you have loaded the class with one classloader then tried to cast it to the same class loaded by another classloader?

Comment: I suspected that this is what is happening. In this case the code is simply marshalling a pojo from xml or json. The code has this problem after the application is redeployed and a new task is submitted to the managed executor service. It seems JBoss is still using the old classloader when running the new task.

Comment: Perhaps you should look in the classloading configuration for JBoss and see if the issue is there.

Comment: When using java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor the issue doesn't appear.